# How to alter Foreign Key reference ON DELETE CASCADE without dropping table

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I have created database tables with foreign key reference `ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT` . However, I set my engine MyISAM so this reference does not work. The primary key is being deleted even if it is used elsewhere as foreign key. How can I fix this issue?
I tried to alter table engine to InnoDB, but even if it is set to InnoDB the foreign references does not work. Moreover, I tried to drop one empty table with foreign key reference and engine MyISAM. Then I tried to add that table, but it does not add. Most probably when I drop table foreign references remain somewhere in schemas.

My query to create table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
    `productid` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `productname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `productcode` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `producttype` varchar(255) NULL
) 
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sales` (
    `salesid` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    `productid` int(10) NOT NULL,
    `quantity` int(10) NOT NULL,
    `price` int(10) NOT NULL,
    `date` datetime NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_sales_productid` 
    FOREIGN KEY (productid) 
    REFERENCES products(productid) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
) 
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

These 2 tables were created with this query as MyISAM. They have data on it which i need.
I run this query to change engine to InnoDB as reference on delete cascade were not working in MyISAM. `'ALTER TABLE products ENGINE=InnoDB;'` `'ALTER TABLE sales ENGINE=InnoDB;'`
But after making them InnoDB, the reference still does not work when I delete product, related productid in sales table becomes NULL.

Comment: 'The primary key is being deleted even if it is used elsewhere as foreign key' what primary key in what table are you talking about? NB sales create table as published is syntactically incorrect - missing comma after primary key

Comment: productid is primary key in products table. And it is foreign key in sales table. Normally, the reference should not let me delete product row which is being used in sales table. But it deletes straightforward. No warning, no restriction.

Comment: You don' t appear to have added the FK back in to sales see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=77765a81eaba9e207ae9e628f6f74c6a

Comment: "the foreign references does not work" -- There are many interpretations for this; please be more specific.

Comment: i meant, delete should be restricted, but it was deleting straightforward. By the way I have fixed it by completely dropping table and creating new one. And I have added backed up data afterward. I thank to P.Salmon for his efforts, I think there was something that I was missing somewhere

Answer (score 1):

As per P.Salmon's demo queries seems valid. You probably missing something in FK references. I suggest you to export 2 tables, the examine it in editor, especially FK references part and make sure engine is InnoDB as it has row-level locking and has what is called referential integrity that involves supporting foreign keys and relationship constraints.